# Assistance visualising data in power BI / power bi report builder

Tags: powerbi, visualization, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following dataset:

[image]

which I want to visualise like this:

[image]

I can do this in either power bi desktop or power bi report builder - the final report doesn't have to be interactive.

How can I achieve this? I was thinking some sort of bar chart, but I've got nowhere with the standard visualisations in power bi.
If I can't achieve it exactly, any hacks / workarounds to get something similar to it gratefully accepted as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power BI, In the `Home` tab in the ribbon, select `More visuals > From AppSource` and then do a search on `Bullet`. I think a Bullet chart could work well for this one.